# Errors nesting objects javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, nest-nested-object

So I seem to be having trouble creating inner nested objects in JS and calling them. I have been looking at various examples but this has been a persisting problem and I would like a bit of explanation to help me understand where I am screwing up. THanks!

```
var cars = {
    make : [
    {   make1 : "ford"},
    {   make2 : "fiat"},
    {   make3 : "toyota" [
        { modelA : "camry"},
        { modelB : "landcruiser"}
        ]
    };
}
console.log(cars.make[2].modelB)
```

Comment: That's a syntax error, you have a semicolon where it doesn't belong, missing a key and a colon etc.

Comment: And the problem is? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: In a general sense, nested object and array literals need to appear in the same place that a simple string value would appear, so if you could say `{ a : "x" }` then you can say `{ a : { b : "y" } }`. The nested items have to follow the same syntax rules as the top level object or array. So use commas, match opening and closing `{}` and `[]`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this.

```
var cars = {
            make : [
            {   make1 : "ford"},
            {   make2 : "fiat"},
            {   make3 : "toyota", 
                 model: [
                    { modelA : "camry"},
                    { modelB : "landcruiser"}
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
var cars = {
makes: [
       { name: "ford"},
       { name : "fiat"},
       { name : "toyota", models: [
               { name : "camry"},
               { name : "landcruiser"}
       ]
       }
]
};
console.log(cars.makes[2].models[1])
```

**Description**

**cars** is an object with one attribute or property **makes**.

**makes** is an array of objects, each with at least one attribute **name** and an optional attribute **models**.

**models** is an array of objects, each with at least one attribute **name**.

Comment: thank you @user2182349.  This is a big breakthrough and I'll be practicing variations from you template!